# Trouble with creating a Selection Sorter counting swaps and comparisons

Tags: java, selection-sort

I am having trouble trying to figure out how many swaps and comparisons for an int array using a Selection Sort in Java. I am confused on where in the loops the swap and comparisons count. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

```
    public class IntSelectionSorter {

public static int count = 0;
public static int count2 = 0;

public static void selectionSort(int[] array)
{
    int startScan;
    int index;
    int minIndex;
    int minValue;

    for (startScan = 0; startScan < (array.length - 1); startScan++)
    {
        minIndex = startScan;
        minValue = array[startScan];

        for (index = startScan + 1; index < array.length; index++)
        {
            count2++;
            if (array[index] < minValue)
            {
                minValue = array[index];
                count++;
                minIndex = index;
            }
        }
        array[minIndex] = array[startScan];
        count++;
        array[startScan] = minValue;
        count++;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: What is the specific problem? What do you expect it to do, and what does it do instead?

Comment: I am creating a Selection Sorter for an int array that is suppose to count the number of swaps and comparisons. I have already created a Bubble Sorter to use the same int array. I am not sure that I have used the swap (count) and comparison (count2) in the proper places on this Selection Sorter. I am getting an answer of 48 swaps and 300 comparisons. If I change where I put the "count" and "count2", I get different answers. I can post the other files too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

count2 seems to be right. count should be changed as follows:

```
for (startScan = 0; startScan < (array.length - 1); startScan++)
{
    minIndex = startScan;
    minValue = array[startScan];

    for (index = startScan + 1; index < array.length; index++)
    {
        count2++;
        if (array[index] < minValue)
        {
            minValue = array[index];
            // count++; delete this
            minIndex = index;
        }
    }
    if (minIndex != startScan) {
        array[minIndex] = array[startScan];
        count++;
        array[startScan] = minValue;
    }
}
```

basically, increment count only when there's is a need to swap, i.e. when there's another number in the array after startScan which is smaller than the value at startScan.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! That makes more sense. However I am getting a number of 0 swaps and 300 comparisons. That doesn't seem correct.

Comment: i ran a test on this and it gave the right answer. Checked for input array [2,1,4,3] and it indeed gives 2 swaps (first for index 0, and the second for index 2). what's the input that you're trying?

Answer (score 0):

public class SortingTest {

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    int[] values = { 1,53,86,21,49,32,90,65,33,11,34,68,54,32,78,80,35,22,96,59,265,44324,123,3123,25435};

    System.out.println("Original Order: ");
    for (int element : values) 
        System.out.print(element + " ");

    IntBubbleSorter.bubbleSort(values);

    System.out.println("\nSorted order: ");
    for (int element : values) 
        System.out.print(element + " ");

    System.out.println();

    System.out.print("\n Bubble Sort Swaps:" + IntBubbleSorter.count);
    System.out.print("\n Bubble Sort Comparisons:" + IntBubbleSorter.count2);

    System.out.println();

    System.out.println("\nOriginal Order: ");
    for (int element : values) 
        System.out.print(element + " ");

    IntSelectionSorter.selectionSort(values);

    System.out.println("\nSorted order: ");
    for (int element : values) 
        System.out.print(element + " ");

    System.out.println();

    System.out.print("\n Selection Sort Swaps:" + IntSelectionSorter.count);
    System.out.print("\n Selection Sort Comparisons:" + IntSelectionSorter.count2);

    System.out.println();

    System.out.println("\nOriginal Order: ");
    for (int element : values) 
        System.out.print(element + " ");

    IntInsertionSorter.insertionSort(values);

    System.out.println("\nSorted order: ");
    for (int element : values) 
        System.out.print(element + " ");

    System.out.println();

    System.out.print("\n Insertion Sort Swaps:" + IntInsertionSorter.count);
    System.out.print("\n Insertion Sort Comparisons:" + IntInsertionSorter.count2);
}
```

}